# Extract string with spaces in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string `a='15/08/2017 TRANSFER OF LAND $610,000 CASH & MTGE'`. I need to extract `'TRANSFER OF LAND'` as one word(with spaces), `'$610,000'` as other and `'CASH & MTGE'`(with spaces) as another word. How can I do this using python? I tried using `split` function. But `split` function doesn't include spaces.

```
b=a.split('15/08/2017',1)[1]
c=b.split()
```

I am getting `['TRANSFER', 'OF', 'LAND', '$610,000', 'CASH', '&', 'MTGE']` If I could also get number of whitespaces after `split`, I could get the result with checking number of empty empty spaces after a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `re` module of python. `findall` function of re is sufficient for your query. Below code will work for you. For the much explanations of terms used, please refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> a = '15/08/2017 TRANSFER OF LAND $610,000 CASH & MTGE'
>>> findall(r'(?<!\S)(?:[$]\S+|[^$\d]+)\b', a)
['TRANSFER OF LAND', '$610,000', 'CASH & MTGE']
```

I hope this suffice your query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> a = '15/08/2017 TRANSFER OF LAND $610,000 CASH & MTGE'
>>> b = a.split()
>>> c = [' '.join(i) for i in [b[1:4], b[4:5], b[5:]]]
>>> #c = ['TRANSFER OF LAND', '$610,000', 'CASH & MTGE']
```